# Why does Java base class constructor call derived class' methods?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a derived Java class override a base class' method. When the base class calls the method, it executes the derived class' function, rather than its own. Why?

```
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Derived d = new Derived();
        System.out.println("Main");
    }
}

class Base {
    void f() {
        System.out.println("Base::f()");
    }

    public Base() {
        f();
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    void f() {
        System.out.println("Derived::f()");
    }

    public Derived() {
        f();
    }
}
```

The code prints Derived::f() twice, I expect it to print Base::f() followed by Derived::f(), as would happen in C++

Comment: It’s because methods in Java are virtual by default. It’s a dangerous practice when a constructor calls a non-final method since you may end up calling it on a not yet initialized instance of a derived class.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, unlike in C++, instance methods are virtual by default. It means that a method call is dispatched at the run time according to the actual run-time class of an object (not at the compile time). In C++, you achieve this behaviour with keyword `virtual`.

Comment: This is not how C++ works. Lets take the following program:

`class a {
public:
 virtual void foo() { std::cout << "a::foo()\n"; }

 a() { foo(); }
};

class b : public a {
public:
 virtual void foo() { std::cout << "b::foo()\n"; }

 b() { foo(); }
};

int main()
{
 B b;

 return 0;
}`

Though f() is virtual, the program will print Base::f() followed by Derived::f(). Base's constructor will set the object's vtable pointer to Base's table, then Derived's consturctor will set it to Derived's table, insuring the constructors call the methods of their own classes.

Comment: @Uri Raz: You can better post it in the first post, to make that point clear.

Comment: @UriRaz, AFAIR, in C++, run-time call resolution through virtual method tables only works when you access an object through a pointer (`b->foo()`). Probably, the calls from the constructors refer to the objects directly without pointers and are bound at the compile time. In Java, an object is always represented by a reference, and therefore, any call is dispatched through virtual method tables (except for possible optimisations for `final` methods).

Comment: @Ruslan Batdalov, in C++ objects have a pointer to their virtual function table. The 2nd thing each constructor does (after calling base class(es) constructor(s)) is to set the pointer to its respective class' virtual function table, and only then proceed to execute its body. That insures a will call a::foo(), and b will call b::foo(). My question is why Java doesn't do that.

Comment: @UriRaz, of course, they have. However, even for virtual methods, they do not always use them. Actually, if a method were called as virtual, `a` constructor would call `b::foo()`. That is the logic of the virtual call: when call `foo()` is reached, the actual run-time type of the object is checked. The run-time type in your example is `b` (even though the call is initiated from `a` constructor). Therefore, `b::foo()` is called. Java does this (always). C++, seemingly, binds this call `foo()` with `a::foo()` statically, not employing the virtual method table in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Your Derived f() method is overriding the Base f() method. If you want to see the Base method try putting super.f(); in the start of the Derived f() method, this will call the super class' f() method.

Comment: The question isn't how to call Base::f() from derived, but rather **why** Base's constructor calls Derive's functions, in contrast to C++.

Comment: The question was asking why Base call to f() is calling the Derived class' method, so I explained it is overridden. At the end it was stated how you expected it to work referencing C++, so I explained how to get the expected result like C++. Not really sure what else to say, the f() is simply not visible directly as it is overridden. Even in Base's constructor is you cast ((Base)this).f() you will still fire the Derived f() method as Base's copy is not directly visible.